java: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows does not exist
I switched from Java 8 to Java 17. The code now doesn't compile
Specifically, imports from the com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows package are now invalid.

java: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows does not exist

However, it does exist. It's just the new compiler being unreasonable. It now refuses to acknowledge its existence for some reason.
compilation error, com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows does no exist

These com.sun.java.swing packages were never intended to be used outside of Java itself, and shouldn't have been used directly. Java now enforces that.
Mark Rotteveel

Alright, but here we are, we reference the package anyway. Java claims to be backwards-compatible, so anything that's legal in an older version should be legal in a newer one
So what do we do?
// MRE. Compilation fails. Amazon Corretto 17

package demos.button;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CheckBoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // you don't expect us to pass strings directly, do you?
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(WindowsLookAndFeel.class.getName());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Check Box demo");
        JPanel mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(layout);
        mainPanel.add(createCheckBox());
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static JCheckBox createCheckBox() {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        return checkBox;
    }
}

Even if I disable the --release option, the code doesn't compile anyway. For example, because ComboPopup's getList() used to look like this
public JList getList();

and now it looks like this
public JList<Object> getList();

So if your ComboPopup implementation used any type arguments, tough luck
// no longer compiles
@Override
public JList<T> getList() {
    return itemList;
}

It doesn't look like backwards-compatibility at all. Isn't it (along with cross-platform support) the whole point of Java?

The solution is to change your code so that it doesn't use com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows classes directly.  In your example, it doesn't look like there is a good reason to do that.

"Java claims to be back-compatible, so anything that's legal in an older version should be legal in a newer one." - >shrug<.  There have been a number of breaking changes since Java 8.  If that is a show-stopper for you, don't upgrade past Java 8.

@StephenC but it's public, isn't it? I should be able to use anything public alright

@life888888 Windows 10

@StephenC breaking changes are fine. Not back-compatible ones are not, on the other hand

Most of the com.sun.* where specific to Sun's (and later Oracle's) implementation of Java, and not meant for general consumption, as they are not actually part of the Java specification, and thus could change and disappear when needed. Even if they are currently included in your Java distribution, they are not exported from the module java.desktop (modularity was introduced in Java 9), because you shouldn't have used them directly in the first place. You could try adding the necessary exports with --add-exports on the commandline or Add-Exports in the manifest of your application.

BTW "Java claims to be backwards-compatible" yes, but that is only valid for the official, supported, public interface ("The java., javax. and org.* packages documented in the Java Platform Standard Edition API Specification")

also check Migrating From JDK 8 to Later JDK Releases

@user85421 Adding the export is not really necessary as there are better ways to do this (some of them introduced in Java 9 specifically for this reason).

Since Java 9, Java is modular, and things you shouldn't be using are not exported from those modules, including public classes that are not part of the API defined by the Java specification. The classes in com.sun.* in most cases are specific to the Sun/Oracle implementation of Java, and sometimes even platform-specific (as is the case for this look-and-feel), and not part of the Java specification.
As such, they are generally considered an implementation detail and not part of any API, and thus not subject to the backwards-compatibility promises of Java. If you'd used a Java implementation of a different vendor, you would likely not have access to them either (because they wouldn't exist).
So, since Java 9, when modules were implemented, you can no longer access these classes, even if they still exist (the package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows is located in the java.desktop module, at least in Windows builds). In theory you can still access them if you add the necessary exports (e.g. with --add-exports on the commandline, or with Add-Exports in them manifest of the application JAR).
However, it is far easier to replace your code with something which will simply work without exports, in a way that Sun and now Oracle have always recommended (e.g. see the Swing tutorial How to Set the Look and Feel which is based on Java 8).
You have multiple options:

Explicitly set the look and feel by class name:
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

I wouldn't recommend this, as it still ties you to Oracle/OpenJDK variants of Java.

Use the name of the look and feel instead of the class name (introduced in Java 9):
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.createLookAndFeel("Windows");

Note that the Java 8 tutorial I linked mentions the names Windows XP and Windows Vista, but the names are actually Windows Classic and Windows. I can only assume that when this feature was introduced in Java 9, they considered the names mentioned in the Java 8 tutorial not right for this.
If the Java implementation or platform doesn't actually have the specified look and feel name, this will result in an UnsupportedLookAndFeelException.

Make it dynamic based on the actual system:
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());




The first option was always the go-to solution if you wanted the UI to look like Windows. I guess that Oracle noticed that and therefore provided the new method you use in option 2, I hadn't seen it before. If needed UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels() can be used to find the correct Windows L&F.

@RobSpoor Indeed, but it is still specific to Oracle/OpenJDK implementations; the third option is actually the most flexible IMHO.

While the most flexible, it also makes the UI a lot different from native applications. That's why I mentioned the getInstalledLookAndFeels() method, it can be used to find the correct Windows L&F. The system L&F can be used as fallback if there are no matches.

@RobSpoor On Windows, getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() will also result in the Windows look and feel. The first and second option will simply result in an error on platforms that don't have the Windows look and feel (which is any non-Windows platform AFAIK).

You're absolutely correct, I got mixed up with getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName().

It can be selected only if the system is applicable.
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

